# Does OS initialize the controllers already initialized by the BIOS?

Tags: linux, windows, operating-system, bios

In fast boot the BIOS skips many modules that can be initialized in the OS. For example it can skip initializing the VGA controller if there is no need to display setup or the startup logo screen. It can also skip Initializing the the EHCI controller or any other USB controller. Then the OS initializes it. My question is even if it is initialized by the BIOS will OS again intialize it.

Comment: It depends upon the OS, but I believe that Linux does initialize again the controllers, because it does not know exactly how the BIOS behave....

Comment: Generally speaking, yes.  The OS will throw away everything the BIOS did and start again from scratch.  (Of course this doesn't apply to DOS!)

Answer (score 0):

Generally yes. The Operating System will re-initialize devices when it loads its own drivers.  However, most low-level chipset initialization (e.g. memory controller) is specific to the chipset/motherboard, and will be done by the BIOS only.